# Eclipse indigo. Commit hotkey don't work

Tags: eclipse, hotkeys, eclipse-indigo

I am having an issue.
In preferences-general-keys I set up ctrl+alt+c team->commit for svn in 'windows', but it doesn't work.

Is this a bug, or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SOLVED]
Window->customize perspestive->Command Groups Availability->there I put a tick to SVN

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This has been annoying me for ages!

Answer (score 0):

There could be a conflict with some other key binding.  Go to Preferences -> General -> Keys.  Look for the specific command and see if there is a conflict.  If so, then unbind the conflicting key binding.

Answer (score 0):

It might be other applications that take over that hotkey. Download [ActiveHotkey](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=18189.0) and check what uses it.